# TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType [moviepy, write_videofile]

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

**WHAT I'M DOING:**

I am writing a video using moviepy. My program successfully renders the audio for the video, but then immediately shoots the following error once it starts rendering the video (full traceback lower down on page):

```
TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

at the specified line in my code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
from os import walk
from random import randint as rand

def makeVideo(videoCounter, picturePath, audioPath, stockPath, musicPath, outputPath, emptyPath):

    #Get files
    myAudioFiles = next(walk(audioPath), (None, None, []))[2]
    myImageFiles = next(walk(picturePath), (None, None, []))[2]

    #Make audio file (without music)
    audio = []
    emptyAudio = AudioFileClip(emptyPath+'\\'+'emptyAudio.mp3')
    for counter1 in range(len(myAudioFiles)):
        theAudio = AudioFileClip(audioPath+'\\'+str(myAudioFiles[counter1]))
        theAudio = theAudio.subclip(0,-0.1)
        audio.append(theAudio)
        audio.append(emptyAudio)
    audioFiles = concatenate_audioclips(audio)
    audioFiles = audioFiles.set_fps(44100)
    audioFiles = audioFiles.volumex(2)

    #Make comment video
    images = []
    emptyImage = ImageClip(emptyPath+'\\'+'emptyImage.png', duration=0.5)
    emptyImage = emptyImage.set_opacity(0)
    for counter2 in range(len(myImageFiles)):
        theImage = ImageClip(picturePath+'\\'+str(myImageFiles[counter2])).set_duration(audio[counter2*2].duration)
        theImage = theImage.resize(2)
        images.append(theImage)
        images.append(emptyImage)
    theImages = concatenate_videoclips(images, method='compose')
    theImages = theImages.set_position(("center"))
    theImages = theImages.set_fps(10)

    #Get stock video
    myStock = next(walk(stockPath), (None, None, []))[2]
    stockFile = VideoFileClip(stockPath+'\\'+str(myStock[0]), target_resolution=(1080, 1920), audio=False)
    stockFile = stockFile.subclip(0.5,-0.5)
    stockFile = stockFile.loop(duration = theImages.duration)
    stockFile = stockFile.set_fps(30)

    #Get background music
    myMusic = next(walk(musicPath), (None, None, []))[2]

    #Make final audio and final video
    with AudioFileClip(musicPath+'\\'+str(myMusic[rand(0,len(myMusic)-1)]), fps=44100) as musicFile:
        musicFile = afx.audio_loop(musicFile, duration=theImages.duration)
        finalAudio = CompositeAudioClip([musicFile, audioFiles])
        finalAudio = finalAudio.set_fps(44100)
        finalVideo = CompositeVideoClip([stockFile, theImages])
        finalVideo = finalVideo.set_audio(finalAudio)
        #v v v this line has the error v v v
        finalVideo.write_videofile(outputPath+'\\'+'finalVideo #'+str(videoCounter)+'.mp4')

PICTURE_PATH = r'C:\Users\jack_l\Documents\REDDIT_TO_YOUTUBE_PYTHON_SELENIUM\topicAndCommentsPictures'       
AUDIO_PATH = r'C:\Users\jack_l\Documents\REDDIT_TO_YOUTUBE_PYTHON_SELENIUM\topicAndCommentsAudio'            
STOCK_PATH = r'C:\Users\jack_l\Documents\REDDIT_TO_YOUTUBE_PYTHON_SELENIUM\redditVideo\stockFootage'         
MUSIC_PATH = r'C:\Users\jack_l\Documents\REDDIT_TO_YOUTUBE_PYTHON_SELENIUM\permanentClips\Atmosphere'        
OUTPUT_PATH = r'C:\Users\jack_l\Documents\REDDIT_TO_YOUTUBE_PYTHON_SELENIUM\redditVideo\finalVideos'         
THUMBNAIL_PATH = r'C:\Users\jack_l\Documents\REDDIT_TO_YOUTUBE_PYTHON_SELENIUM\redditVideo\thumbnails'       
PERMANENT_PATH = r'C:\Users\jack_l\Documents\REDDIT_TO_YOUTUBE_PYTHON_SELENIUM\permanentClips\deadTopics'    
EMPTY_FILES_PATH = r'C:\Users\jack_l\Documents\REDDIT_TO_YOUTUBE_PYTHON_SELENIUM\permanentClips\emptyFiles'  
UPLOAD_TO_YOUTUBE_PATH = r'C:\Users\jack_l\Documents\REDDIT_TO_YOUTUBE_PYTHON_SELENIUM\uploadToYoutube'      

makeVideo(1, PICTURE_PATH, AUDIO_PATH, STOCK_PATH, MUSIC_PATH, OUTPUT_PATH, EMPTY_FILES_PATH)
```

**WHAT I KNOW AND HAVE DONE:**

- My program hasn't worked since I switched from Python 3.10 to 3.9.
- I've set `IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = r'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI\magick.exe'` in config_defaults.py
- I've upgraded moviepy to the most recent version (1.0.3)

**FULL TRACEBACK:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jack_l\Documents\REDDIT_TO_YOUTUBE_PYTHON_SELENIUM\makeVideos.py", line 65, in <module>
    makeVideo(1, PICTURE_PATH, AUDIO_PATH, STOCK_PATH, MUSIC_PATH, OUTPUT_PATH, EMPTY_FILES_PATH)
  File "c:\Users\jack_l\Documents\REDDIT_TO_YOUTUBE_PYTHON_SELENIUM\makeVideos.py", line 53, in makeVideo
    finalVideo.write_videofile(outputPath+'\\'+'finalVideo #'+str(videoCounter)+'.mp4')
  File "c:\users\jack_l\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Users\jack_l\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration 
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "c:\users\jack_l\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Users\jack_l\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 135, in use_clip_fps_by_default
    return f(clip, *new_a, **new_kw)
  File "c:\users\jack_l\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Users\jack_l\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "C:\Users\jack_l\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 300, in write_videofile
    ffmpeg_write_video(self, filename, fps, codec,
  File "C:\Users\jack_l\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_writer.py", line 213, in ffmpeg_write_video
    with FFMPEG_VideoWriter(filename, clip.size, fps, codec = codec,
  File "C:\Users\jack_l\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_writer.py", line 88, in __init__
    '-r', '%.02f' % fps,
TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the path of my python file's directory as an "extra path" in my IDE (VScode).

Comment: Nice! I started getting this recently, until last week my script was working. Can you explain what do you mean by "my python file's directory "?